# Using the electromagnetic field tensor to derive Maxwell-Faraday equation

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations

I'm currently going through Byron and Fuller, and problem 1.13 is a problem about deriving the electromagnetic field tensor.  The field tensor we derive is the complex version:

$$F = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & H_z & -H_y & -iE_x \\
-H_z & 0 & H_x & -iE_y \\
H_y & -H_x & 0 & -iE_z \\
iE_x & iE_y & iE_z & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Then Byron asks that we derive the Maxwell equations.  However, I'm having a bit of a problem doing that.

We can using the Binachi identity to arrive at:

\begin{align*}
\partial_l F_{ik} + \partial_i F_{kl} + \partial_k F_{li} &= 0 \\
l = 2 \quad i = 4 \quad &k = 3 \\
\partial_y (i E_z) + \partial_t (-H_x) + \partial_z(-i E_y) &= 0 \\
i(\nabla \times \vec{E})_x &= \partial_t H_x \\
\text{Similarly} \qquad& \\
i(\nabla \times \vec{E})_y &= \partial_t H_y \\
i(\nabla \times \vec{E})_z &= \partial_t H_z \\
\nabla \times \vec{E} = -i \frac{\partial \vec{H}}{\partial t} \\
\end{align*}

But the Maxwell-Faraday Equation is listed as:

$$\nabla \times \vec{E} = -\frac1{c} \frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t}$$

How do I get to that point from here?  Is it true that $ic\vec{H} = \vec{B}$?

Comment: Why there are the imaginary units in front of the E field? This is "strange", try to compare with: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_tensor

Comment: It's the form given in the book.  I have also seen this form referenced in one other place while searching for ways to reconcile this with the example derivations I've seen.  https://mathpages.com/home/kmath647/kmath647.htm (Though it ought to be noted that this page uses B in place of H, which is even more confusing.)

Comment: The derivation of this form involves using $x_4 = ict$ and $A_4 = i\varphi$ specifically.

Comment: I just realized that I answered my own question with that final comment.  I took the derivative with respect to $t$ not $ict$

Comment: exactly.. it's because you are using "imaginary time", so no problems at all.